# Inheritance Mapping Fluent NHibernate results in unnecessary joins

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

The issue is when selecting directly on the base model the generated SQL performs an left outer select on the subclasses.

Basemodel.

```
public class Node
{
   public virtual int ID {get;set;}
   public virtual string Url {get;set;}
}

public class CMSPage : Node
{
   public virtual string FieldA {get;set;}
   public virtual string FieldB {get;set;}
}

public class Article : Node 
{
   public virtual string FieldC {get;set;}
   public virtual string FieldD {get;set;}
}
```

My Mapping is

```
public class NodeMap : ClassMap<Node>
{
   Table("Nodes");
   Id(x => x.ID, "Node_ID");
   Map(x => x.Url);
}    

public class CMSPageMap: SubclassMap<CMSPage>
{
   Table("CMSPages");
   Map(x => x.FieldA);
   Map(x => x.FieldB);
}    

public class ArticleMap: SubclassMap<Article>
{
   Table("Articles");
   Map(x => x.FieldC);
   Map(x => x.FieldD);
}
```

When querying direct on Nodes using ICriteria

```
  var store = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Node));           
  store.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Url", filter.Url));                
  store.SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
   .Add(Projections.Property("ID"), "ID")                   
   .Add(Projections.Property("Url"), "Url"));                
  store.SetResultTransformer(new 
  AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(Node)));
  Node result = store.UniqueResult<Node>();
```

The sql generated is

```
SELECT this_.Node_ID     as y0_, this_.Url         as y7_ FROM   Nodes this_
   left outer join CMSPages this_1_
   on this_.Node_ID = this_1_.Node_ID
   left outer join Articles this_2_
   on this_.Node_ID = this_2_.Node_ID
WHERE  this_.Url = '/' /* @p0 - Url */
```

How do i prevent the join selects

Ive tried using both Abstract and KeyColumn according to https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/232034/Inheritance-mapping-strategies-in-Fluent-Nhibernat

Comment: I only see sql as an option here unfortunatly.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass mapping purpose is to have a Table per class hierarchy. Means you have one table for any child class. You can find examples on the [documentation](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/inheritance.html) about all kind of supported inheritance by NHibernate.

I think you need to try "Table per subclass" strategy, using a `JoinedSubclassMap<T>`. The two subclass tables have primary key associations to the superclass table so the relational model is actually a one-to-one association. Documentation 9.1.2. Table per subclass

If you want to keep the `SubclassMap<T>` you must use a discriminator. 9.1.3. Table per subclass, using a discriminator.